# How to find and click the button by "onclick" with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

There are 2 buttons in a page, and the difference between these 2 buttons is `"onclick"`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 96px;" type="button" id="YesBtn" onclick="check_security('security_div0')">OK</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 96px;" type="button" id="YesBtn" onclick="check_security('wlan1security_div0')">OK</button>
```

I was thinking to use `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='update-container-id']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/button").click()
```

But it responses the error as below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button id="YesBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Does anyone can help me to click the 2nd button correctly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Share the method which you used the xpath on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with the x-path `//button[@onclick="check_security('wlan1security_div0')"]`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"check_security('wlan1security_div0')\"]").click()
```

Using Action class,

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"check_security('wlan1security_div0')\"]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

using java script executor,

```
driver.execute_script("javascript:check_security('wlan1security_div0')")
```

Comment: I use the x-path method, and it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have provided, to click on the button using the `onclick()` event you can use the following solution:

- First Element(css_selector):

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-primary#YesBtn[onclick*='security_div0']").click()
  ```
- First Element(xpath):

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and @id='YesBtn'][@onclick=\"check_security('security_div0')\"]").click()
  ```
- Second Element(css_selector):

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-primary#YesBtn[onclick*='wlan1security_div0']").click()
  ```
- Second Element(xpath):

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and @id='YesBtn'][@onclick=\"check_security('wlan1security_div0')\"]").click()
  ```

Comment: I prefer to use the x-path method, and it also works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you are using a really long xpath which will be difficult to maintain. You can narrow it down further.

Now, some xpaths you can try:

1) Get the *second* button with the id `YesBtn` (assuming there are only two buttons with that attribute) :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@id= 'YesBtn'])[2]");
```

2) Find by the `onclick` attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick= \'check_security(\'wlan1security_div0\')\']");
```

Answer (score 0):

**button1** with **HTML** :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 96px;" type="button" id="YesBtn" onclick="check_security('security_div0')">OK</button>
```

**XPATH :**

```
//button[text()='OK' and @onclick="check_security('security_div0')"]
```

**button2** with **HTML** :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 96px;" type="button" id="YesBtn" onclick="check_security('wlan1security_div0')">OK</button>
```

**HTML:**

```
//button[text()='OK' and @onclick="check_security('wlan1security_div0')"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
  buttonVar = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(cssSel)
  ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(buttonVar).click(buttonVar ).perform()

except Exception as ex:
  print("button not found)
```

Firefox gives you several option you can use with selenium find_element or elements;

1. by pressing f12 to bring up the inspector,
2. use the "pick an item" icon in the left corner to select the item you want to view.
3. This will highlight the text for that item in the inspector, which you can then right click on to bring up a menu where you select "copy" where there are at least 2 find_element options, css_selecor & xpath.

I personally don't like xpath. 
They are sometimes long & unruly to work with but whatever suits your style. In my case css_selector works fine.