# Code to find a pattern where a fixed string is followed by any positive integer followed by another fixed string

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, onclick, pattern-matching

I am navigating a dynamic webpage with Selenium. The page loads content dynamically based on what link a user clicks, without affecting the webpage's address. For example, the following is the HTML source code on one of the links:

[image]

As can be seen, the JS onclick event for this particular location is `openLocation(L_52)`. For another link, it can be `openLocation(L_73)`, etc. I can simulate a click on this link with the following line of code:

```
location = driver.execute_script("openLocation('L_52')")
```

I am trying to navigate through each of these links. The problem is, these JS onclick events are not in serial order; they are in the pattern of `openLocation(L_x)`, where `x` can be any random positive integer.

So, I could not write a for loop such as the following to navigate through them all in a serial fashion:

```
for k in range(num_locations):
    location = driver.execute_script("openLocation('L_{}')".format(str(k)))
```

This leads to missing some locations whenever location `n+1` is not present after location `n`.

So, instead, I had to resort to going though all the dynamic links in the page manually, list down the location numbers in a list, and then going through that list to navigate each of these locations:

```
loc_nums = [52, 53, 54, 55, 101, 56, 6, 7, 41, 57, 58]
for l in loc_nums:
    location = driver.execute_script("openLocation('L_{}')".format(str(l)))
```

But obviously this approach is not sustainable if the number of links is high. So, I want to know if there's a way to run any JS onclick event that has the string `openLocation('L_` followed by any positive integer followed by the string `')`.

**P.S.:** I know how to match a pattern in a ***given*** string with regular expressions:

```
import re
re.findall(r"openLocation\('L_[0-9]+'\)", "openLocation('L_52')")
```

But the whole point of this question is that the strings are not given - I don't know what the exact name of the onclick event in the next link is going to be, without clicking on it first, as its a dynamic webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Look under '4.3. Locating by XPath':

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

[Here is a practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51415822/9757927) of how to do it, adapt and fit it into your use case. You can use it to detect the exact name and then pass the name to your `execute_script`

Answer (score 0):

You can locate all the the elements matching the pattern in `onclick` and extract the numbers from there

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[onclick^="openLocation("L_"][onclick$=")"]')
loc_nums = [re.search(r'\d+', x).group() for x in data]
```

If the links are opened in a new tab/window and the elements in `data` don't became stale you can skip the numbers extracting step

```
[driver.execute_script(x.get_attribute('onclick')) for x in data]
```